# UnauthorizedAccessException while getting files

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, directory, getfiles

I am creating an application which finds duplication in files. When I search files like:

```
try
{
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(
        directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.Length; i++)
    {
      //decisions
    }
}

catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

it says

> Access to path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin....... ' is denied.

I want if a folder is not accessible then move to the next but execution of program stops at `Directory.GetFiles` method.

Comment: Let's call it a feature and not a bug.  No sane user is going to put up with a program that goes zombie for *minutes* while it enumerates every file on the c:\ drive.  A terabyte is a big number.

Comment: @Hans who says the app is running a UI when the code executes?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a class that will work:

```
public static class FileDirectorySearcher
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Search(string searchPath, string searchPattern)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = GetFileSystemEntries(searchPath, searchPattern);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            yield return file;
        }

        IEnumerable<string> directories = GetDirectories(searchPath);

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            files = Search(directory, searchPattern);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string directory)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> subDirectories = null;
        try
        {
            subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }

        if (subDirectories != null)
        {
            foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
            {
                yield return subDirectory;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFileSystemEntries(string directory, string searchPattern)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = null;
        try
        {
            files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can the use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> filesOrDirectories = FileDirectorySearcher.Search(@"C:\", "*.txt");

foreach (string fileOrDirectory in filesOrDirectories)
{
   // Do something here.
}
```

It's recursive, but the use of yield gives it a low memory footprint (under 10KB in my testing). If you want only files that match the pattern and not directories as well just replace `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` with `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: That code has a major bug... because EnumerateDirectories will return an IEnumerable and then when you iterate over the IEnumerable you will get the UnauthorizedAccessException.. I've updated your code above.

Comment: Hi @BlakeNiemyjski, I've been looking at the code but have been unable to reproduce the problem that you said your edit addresses. Can you tell me the specifc steps to reproduce it?

Comment: Your code was picking up System Folders like the recycle bin. I'd run your code as an administrator and point it to your windows drive

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski I tried it on a Windows 2008 R2 server as Admin, on an XP workstation as standard user, and on an XP workstation as Admin with `FileDirectorySearcher.Search(@"C:\", "*.*");`. I still couldn't reproduce an **uncaught** UnauthorizedAccessException. As an admin it enumerated the RECYCLER folder's contents and as a standard user it caught the exception and kept right on going.

Comment: I was seeing this issue on Windows 7 x64. I pointed it to both my C drive and my other hard drives. Try enabling show system and hidden folders in Explorer..

Comment: Works, but I also had to catch `DirectoryNotFoundException` when enumerating the WSL filesystem from Windows, found when testing this on my home directory.

Comment: Actually, also PathTooLongException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories?view=net-5.0