# Basic way to Enumerate a File List From a directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Hi all am working with Directories and Files Counting Software..

Here, When I get or search Files from `C:\` or `D:\` it throws `UnAuthorizedAccessException`

I want to Enumerate Files Ignoring the file/Directory which is Inaccessible

How to ??  C# Visual Studio 2008 Exactly .NET Framework 3.5 only.

**My code**

```
var files = FastDirectoryEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.reg.zip", 
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .GroupBy(f => f.Name).Select(g => g.First());
```

Here Am Taking files which ends with `.reg.zip`

I want to search it on my Whole Computer.. But the Exception..

VS 2008 Default User.. I Tried `app.manifest` with

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but even though Exception.. while Searching in `SystemVolumeInformation` Directory..

Comment: Seconded, an example of the methodology you are using would really help. Also, under what profile is VS running? What are the permissions on that account?

Comment: `FastDirectoryEnumerator` is not part of the .net framework. The execption is happening inside there. If it is your code, you need to show that too. If it is someone else's code, you need to ask them for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548012/unauthorizedaccessexception-while-getting-files

Comment: No no.. I Got it from CodeProject.Com [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator)

Comment: `but even though Exception` What exception? In what code?

Comment: `UnAuthorizedAccessException` While Searching Through `SystemVolumeInformation` Directory of `D:\`

Comment: @phillip `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` This is from .NET 4.0 but am Using .NET 3.5 only..

Comment: Why not just catch the exception and continue along?

Comment: In the example @phillip gives, you will see it catches the `UnAuthorizedAccessException` thrown exception and ignores it to 'keep going'. You would have to break out of your fluent linq pattern to be able to catch those exceptions I think.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain am searching simply like `FastDirectoryEnumerator.EnumerateFiles("D:\\","*.reg.zip",SearchOption.AllDirectories);` So here The SystemVolumeInformation Directory is Included by the .NET by Default.. How can i Prevent Searching such Direcotories????

Comment: @Gokul is the increased speed of `FastDirectoryEnumerator` important to you?

Comment: @CodeBeard Without Linq.??? or .. May be I can edit `FastDirectoryEnumerator` Class .. but I Need Help to Go Through.. AM Sorry for my level...

Comment: @CodeBeard Yes sir, Because I have got more than 125,324 files like that.. so i to get count .. a bit faster..

Comment: @Gokul I may be wrong, but you are using the `FastDirectoryEnumerator` to enumerate the files, the exception is being thrown 'somewhere' as you work through the filing system. I am not familiar with this library, but you would have to trap that exception and discard it without leaving the enumeration.

Comment: Yes sir.. I have to.. @CodeBeard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start by saying this is not the best advice. However, it is a place to start.
My answer is two fold:

Firstly, I think you have prematurely optimised by using the `FastDirectoryEnumerator` before understanding the filing system level security issues you will face with your project. As such, if time permits, I would recommend a **simpler** solution as recommended in the post linked to by @phillip in the comments ([UnauthorizedAccessException while getting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548012/unauthorizedaccessexception-while-getting-files)). For a remotely modern machine 120k files shouldn't be a problem.

Secondly, looking at the speed stats of the `FastDirectoryEnumerator` I can see the appeal of using it. Digging into the code a little, I can see that it doesn't protect you in any way from permissions exceptions when used as you have done. It is essentially procedural code wrapped inside an IEnumerable MoveNext method. The MoveNext method itself, has been made recursive for sub-directory processing.

I am not able to test this next bit, so you will have to experiment. If you want to hack around with the `FastDirectoryEnumerator` the first thing you might want to try is a `try catch` block around the creation of the new FileData object.

`public FileData Current
            {
                get { return new FileData(m_path, m_win_find_data); }
            }`

If that doesn't work, you would have to work through the `GetNext()` method to trap the exception in the right place. You might need to go as far as implementing a [NullObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern for `FileData`.
I hope that helps in some way.